# AngularJS MVC WebApplication pages not loading

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a basic AngularJS MVC application and I cannot load the pages. When opening the partial views they work just fine but when I click on the nav bar they do not load.

Tried to debug and everything and no luck. There are no errors or anything. Not sure if I made a mistake when coding or there might be some compatibility issues or something with the packages.

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2017 version 15.9.16, Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.7.03062.

Project Structure

[image: Project Structure]

_Layout.cshtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - Suitability Escalation Tool</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/lstview">List View</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#!/newesc">New Escalation</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div id="body">
        @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
        <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
            @RenderBody()
        </section>
    </div>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

webApp.js

```
angular.module('App', ['AngularDemo.DashboardController',
    'AngularDemo.ListViewController',
    'AngularDemo.NewEscalationController'
])


    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/Dashboard',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/lstview', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/ListView',
            controller: 'ListViewCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/newesc', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/NewEscalation',
            controller: 'NewEscalationCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
        // Specify HTML5 mode (using the History APIs) or HashBang syntax.
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');

    }]);

angular.module('AngularDemo.NewEscalationController', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('NewEscalationCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.TestModel =
            {
                TestId: '',
                TestName: '',
                TestDetails: ''
            };

        $scope.TestList = {};
        $http.get('/Home/PopulateTestList').success(function (data) {
            $scope.TestList = data;
        });
    });

angular.module('AngularDemo.DashboardController', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('DashboardCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Message = "Edit in Part 2 is coming soon";
    });

angular.module('AngularDemo.ListViewController', ['ngRoute'])
    .controller('ListViewCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.Message = "Delete in Part 2 is coming soon";
    });
```

ListView.cshtml example

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListView";
}

<h2>ListView</h2>

{{Message}}
```

Browser View

[image: Browser View]

As mentioned when I try to open the cshtml files individually they open just fine. However when I am clicking in my navbar nothing happens, it is just empty.

Comment: Try to change href from `href='#!/lstview'` to `href="#!lstview"`

Comment: No luck, still the same issue

Answer (score -1):

Solved. Some dependency issues in BundleConfig.cs file apparently.